# Is it fine to use “锻炼” as in "good practice" or not?

Tags: translation, vocabulary, simplified-characters

The sentence in question is "我觉得留学是一种很好锻炼" Can I use “锻炼” in this context?

Comment: The sentence is perfect. Note 锻炼 means 'harden through overcoming challenges',  so in this context it's not merely good practice, but the personal growth/maturing from living in a new place away from home.

Comment: This is a good thinking. You can do this If you feel happy.

Comment: In this context it would mean something closer to "good training/exercise", similarly to the use in 锻炼身体。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to express: *I think studying aboard is a good practice*, then your Chinese sentence "我觉得留学是一种很好锻炼" doesn't connote the same meaning in my opinion.

"我觉得留学是一种很好锻炼" means "**I think studying aboard is a good way to train ourselves**." The sentence doesn't specify the areas(willpower, ability to live alone and etc.) on which we can get trained.

Well, "*studying aboard is a good practice*" is like saying 出国留学是一种很好的实践 in Chinese.

**Note** that you should add a 的 in your sentence to make it more natural: 我觉得留学是一种很好**的**锻炼.

Answer (score 2):

锻炼 probably means something different than "good practice" in this context.

Its meaning is closer to "tempering one's willpower" or "psychological training", as well as "improve one's abilities in various subjects".

IMO, "good practice" means "a good way to do something" or "something good to do", both of which are different from ""

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely.

Check out **Oxford**'s definition of 锻炼：

> 3 磨砺 toughen
>
> 锻炼意志
> temper one's will power
>
> 他在战争的熔炉中锻炼过。
> He had been steeled in the furnace of war.

Comment: 我觉得 "good practice" 可能不是这么理解的，虽然你的回答没问题

Comment: I think you’re looking at this backwards. OP is obviously doing a E-C translation: “good practice” is not a translation of 锻炼 but vice-versa. “Good practice” as a phrase connotes more than it does literally.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean that "something is a good practice" can be translated into CN as (某某)是一种很好的锻炼. That depends *a lot* on context and I'd always prefer 某某是一种很好的**做法**(行为方式, etc.) as a translation.

Comment: I agree with iBug. Good practice in this context should mean a good way/means/habit to do something. Example: Giving your code sufficient comment is good practice.